# No permission to modify files in my own &HOME directory

Tags: permissions, fedora

I've been trying to update my ~/.fonts.conf file but it just won't work.

I tried going "su" to move or "chmod" it but the same problem.

SELinux is set to permissive and I don't understand why it is not working.

see some outputs...

```
% sudo -i mv /home/marc/.fonts.conf /home/marc/Downloads/
% mv: cannot move `/home/marc/.fonts.conf' to `/home/marc/Downloads/.fonts.conf':Operation not permitted
```

I also tried being root "su -" and the same error!

trying just to edit on Nano or another editor. gives me "permission denied"

here are the permissions for the file checked by ls -la...

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 marc marc 91 May  4 17:45 .fonts.conf
```

I use Fedora 15(beta)

Am I missing something? Please, any help is appreciated.

OBS: *When installing fedora 15 I decided to keep my home partition and I remember
a message saying that SElinux had troubles trying to fix permissions for my user and proposing me to check those settings myself but no link or something about where to
them. :S*

Comment: `Operation not permitted` ≠ `Permission denied`

Comment: Does 'cp' work?

Comment: yes it does but I want to overwrite it

Answer (score 1):

If `cp` works then we know that you can write to the target directory, so when `mv` fails it must be because you can't remove (unlink in unix speak) the file from the source directory.

Now "Operation not permitted" is `EPERM` and according to the `unlink(2)` manual page there are two ways to get that when unlinking a file:

```
   EPERM (Linux only)
          The file system does not allow unlinking of files.

   EPERM or EACCES
          The directory containing pathname has the sticky  bit  (S_ISVTX)
          set  and  the  process's effective UID is neither the UID of the
          file to be deleted nor that of the directory containing it,  and
          the  process  is  not  privileged  (Linux:  does  not  have  the
          CAP_FOWNER capability).
```

To be honest both of those seem unlikely, but you should certainly check the permissions on your home directory by doing:

```
    ls -ld /home/marc
```

If the sticky bit is set you will see a `t` character at the end of the mode string.

Incidentally the important thing to realise here is that when deleting a file on a unix system it is the permissions on the directory you are removing it from which matter, not the permissions on the file being removed.